# grails number (double) format in view

Tags: grails, view, formatting, numbers

I'm new to Grails (2.2.0) and try to figure out how to format double values in the views. I have a lot of them therefore I would prefer some code in one of the config files if possible.

All values in the views are formatted with g:field ... type="number" ...

In resources.groovy I have this

```
beans = {
localeResolver(SessionLocaleResolver) {
defaultLocale= Locale.ENGLISH
Locale.setDefault (Locale.ENGLISH)
}
}
```

And in messages.properties I used

```
default.number.format=#'###'###.#
```

I don't need i18n. I deleted all other files in there.

This problem is in the views only. All data is persisted correctly.

Here some examples what I want for the views:

Input 10
Output 10

Input 0
Output 0

Input 0.775
Output 0.775

Input 0.7
Output 0.7

Input 1234567.12345
Output 1'234'567.12345

The last example is not the standard format for ENGLISH. Instead of the thousand seperator , I want '

I thought if I use

```
default.number.format=#'###'###.#
```

I don't need to format every value with g:formatNumber.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Here are my questions:

Why does the default.number.format=#'###'###.# not work in messages.properties?

For example I have this in my view:

```
<g:field name="mydouble" size="8" maxlength="20" type="number" value="${fieldValue(bean: myInstance, field: 'mydouble')}"/>
```

How do I use the g:formatNumber tag on this field. I have read the Grails documentation but obviously I have problems understanding it.

I wrote that I'm a beginner and therefore it's possible that I'm missing something that for someone who knows Grails is quite obvious.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Seems like you know what you have to do.

Comment: No, otherwise I wouldn't have asked. ;-)

Comment: interesting puzzle, would you mind making sure to post back when you have it figured out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, however see if this works for you:

```
<g:field value="${g.formatNumber(number: fieldValue(bean: personInstance, field: 'minPrice'), format: g.message(code: 'default.number.format'))}" />
```

Comment: I get an Error 500: Internal Server Error  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: ""  Nevertheless, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fieldValue` when rendering your numbers in the GSP.

```
<g:field value="${fieldValue(bean: personInstance, field: 'minPrice')}" />
```

Not sure if that is the problem with it not using defaults or not because you're missing some details from your question.  So shot in the dark here.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to use a `'` as decimal separator? Try such formatting method:

```
class NumberUtilities {
    static String format(double d) {
        def format = new DecimalFormat()
        def symbols = format.decimalFormatSymbols
        symbols.groupingSeparator = '\''
        format.decimalFormatSymbols = symbols
        return format.format(d)
    }
}
```

Then in your view write `${NumberUtilities.format(1234567.12345)}`.

This is just an idea, add more formatting to the method depending on what other formatting rules you need.